# Create backend to store the conversation data using node.js for bot framework

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework

Communication between Bot and user is working fine. I am able to print on the log and create the table "**dataBT**" in the storage. However, I would want to store the content of user conversation with the bot into azure storage account.

Could someone advice me on how to do so? I'm in need of help with storing the data into azure storage table.

```
var restify = require('restify');
var builder = require('botbuilder');
var botbuilder_azure = require("botbuilder-azure");

var server = restify.createServer();
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, function () {
   console.log('%s listening to %s', server.name, server.url); 
});

var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
    appId: process.env.MicrosoftAppId,
    appPassword: process.env.MicrosoftAppPassword,
    openIdMetadata: process.env.BotOpenIdMetadata 
});

server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen());

var tableName = 'dataBT';
var azureTableClient = new botbuilder_azure.AzureTableClient(tableName, process.env['AzureWebJobsStorage']);
var tableStorage = new botbuilder_azure.AzureBotStorage({ gzipData: false }, azureTableClient);

// Create your bot with a function to receive messages from the user
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector);
bot.set('storage', tableStorage);

const logUserConversation = (event) => {
console.log('message: ' + event.text);
};

// Middleware for logging
bot.use({
    receive: function (event, next) {
        logUserConversation(event);
        next();
    },
    send: function (event, next) {
        logUserConversation(event);
        next();
    }
});

bot.dialog('cards', [
  function (session) {

    session.send('Test1');
    var msg = new builder.Message(session)
        .attachmentLayout(builder.AttachmentLayout.carousel)
        .textFormat(builder.TextFormat.xml)
        .attachments([
          new builder.HeroCard(session)
                .title('Test1')
                .images([
                  builder.CardImage.create(session, 'imgURL')
                ])
                .buttons([builder.CardAction.dialogAction(session, 'Card1', null, 'Here')
                  ])
        ]);
        msg.addAttachment (
            new builder.HeroCard(session)
                .title("Test2")
                .images([
                    builder.CardImage.create(session, "imgUrl")
                ])
                .buttons([
                    builder.CardAction.dialogAction(session, "Card2", null, "Here")
                ])
        );

    session.endDialog(msg)
  }
]).triggerAction({
matches: 'Greetings'})

//Adding of new card
bot.dialog('Card1', [
  function (session) {
    var msg1 = new builder.Message(session).sourceEvent({
    //specify the channel
    facebook: {
      text:"Card1"
    }
  });

    session.endDialog(msg1)
    session.beginDialog('card1link');
  }
]).triggerAction({
matches: 'card1'})

bot.dialog('card1link', [
    function (session, args, next) {
        builder.Prompts.choice(session, '1. Card2\n2. Card3\n', ['1', '2'], {
            retryPrompt: "Please pick your choice.\n1. Card2\n2. Card3\n",
            maxRetries: 1
        });
    },
    function (session, args, next) {
        if (args.response) {
            var choice = args.response.entity;
            switch (choice) {
                case '1':
                    session.replaceDialog('Card2');
                    break;
                case '2':
                    session.replaceDialog('Card3');
                    break;
            }
        }
        else{
            session.send("Sorry");
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: What is the purpose of saving the user conversation? Is this something you need for analytical purposes or do you want to show their history on the WebChat channel. The best solution will depend on the purpose of the data. At the moment you only save the state.

Comment: You can directly leverage **Manage custom state data with Azure Cosmos DB or Azure Table Storage** without  **intercept messages**

Comment: @Mick , for analytical purposes. What would your suggestions be?

Comment: You're missing an `intents` variable even though you're using it in a method, and also using regular dialogs with `triggerActions`. Are you using `LuisRecognizers`? 

Regarding Analytical purposes, you'll have to be more specific... Are you okay with LUIS Intents and entities or do you just want to store entire conversations and then run the data through an analytics pipeline?

Comment: @StevenG. I am using LuisRecognizers. I want to store the entire conversation from user input to message return to user.